# SSHFS for OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: ssh, sftp, osx-mountain-lion

In the past I used SSHFS to mount drives, so I could easily work on remote machines with software from my machine. However, when I was at the MacFUSE project page, I noticed that SSHFS has been long since deprecated.

What are people using with Mountain Lion to mount drives? Is it built-in to OSX yet, or has some other project completely replaced the functionality brought to us by SSHFS?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: In the past I used "SSHFS GUI" to mount drives. It looks very similar to the the `Finder >> Go >> Connect to server...` interface.

+1 -> m01 - I'm currently using your solution, but if anyone knows a GUI I would love to hear about it.

Comment: good question, as i've been looking for answer to it also for a while.

Comment: "Software tools commonly used by programmers" means *software that I use to accomplish programming tasks*, not *software that I happen to use, and I'm also a programmer.*

Comment: The software in question is a utility to enable a developer to easily attach to a remote server and use their native IDE for development. Therefore, it is dissimilar from a question about iTunes, where someone likes to listen to music while developing.

Comment: This is a software tool very widely used for programming. This is IMHO an unfair call from the SO community.

Comment: Guys, just use Flag: request moderator attention, type: move to apple site.

Comment: should be short answer here: `brew install sshfs`. We are @ SO!

Comment: I recently forked the GUI you mentioned: https://github.com/dstuecken/sshfs-gui You may would like to give it a try as well?

Answer (score 73):

OSXFUSE seems to work. I just downloaded the two OSXFUSE and SSHFS packages from http://osxfuse.github.com (the links are on the right hand side), and ran:

```
sshfs user@host:/dir /mnt/somelocaldirectory
```

EDIT: if you want a GUI, you might want to try [sshfs-gui](http://code.google.com/p/sshfs-gui/), though I haven't tried it myself.

Personally, I'd use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/), though it doesn't technically do the same as what SSHFS does, but maybe it's enough for your purposes. It will let you browse files that you can access via an ssh connection, and seems to have options for editing them as well.

Comment: +1 This works, but I am still looking for a GUI. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't realise you were looking for a GUI - I've updated my answer accordingly. The SSHFS GUI page suggests that it should work with OSXFUSE in MacFUSE compatibility mode..

Comment: MacFusion works great for me, see this fork: https://github.com/elDeveloper/macfusion2/

Comment: +1 for Cyberduck. Works just fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [OSXFuse wiki](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS), you can use [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org) with a simple tweak, e.g. moving the old sshfs-static and linking it to the new one by OSXFuse as below. I've done this and it works fine.

```
cd /Applications/Macfusion.app/Contents/PlugIns/sshfs.mfplugin/Contents/Resources
mv sshfs-static sshfs-static.orig
ln -s /usr/local/bin/sshfs sshfs-static
```

Comment: A patched version of MacFusion for 10.8 is available [here](http://patjack.co.uk/macfusion-64-bit-ready-for-lion-mountain-lion/).

Answer (score 6):

Back in the Leopard days, I was using SSHFS as well, and it worked ok, as long as you didn't push it too hard (large files or spotty network coverage).

I just setup [Expandrive](https://www.expandrive.com) on my new Retina MBP and it works pretty well. (auto re-connects on wake, no hiccups).  All I had to do was to register my SSH agent `ssh-add -K` for the private key, and it's been smooth sailing so far.

I've tried on both Lion and Mountain Lion, and it seems to work pretty well. For $40, it's totally worth it to me.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the answer, but I'm a poor college student and I need an open source or free solution.

Comment: 40$ to do the same thing as a one-line command on your terminal ? Sounds like a waste of money to me but each to his own !